# "Invalid Heap Size" error when writing ASM.js by hand

Tags: javascript, webassembly, asm.js

I'm trying to write some performance intensive js code so I figured I'd give writing asm.js a try. However whenever I try to instantiate my module with a heap I get the following error in both Node.js and latest Chrome:

```
Linking failure in asm.js: Invalid heap size
```

Here is a minimal set of asm code which reproduces the error. Here's the module definition:

```
function myModule(stdlib, foreign, heap) {
    "use asm"

    var heap8 = new stdlib.Uint8Array(heap);
    function init() {

        heap8[0] = 100;

    }

    return { init : init };

}
```

And here's how I instantiate it:

```
const buffer = new Uint8Array( 80 );
const result = myModule(window, null, buffer.buffer);
result.init();
```

Why am I getting an invalid heap size error?

Thanks!

Comment: Because your buffer size isn't a power of 2. Also, asm.js isn't really meant to be written by hand, it's a compiler target.

Comment: 64 doesn't work either. After looking at this cached page for asm and some manual experimenting it seems that the heap size must be at least 64kb and power of two. And I understand the typical use case is to compile it but for simple cases it doesn't seem all that bad to write.

Here's the referenced cached page:
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XxJzXhLJJ5gJ:https://danigb.github.io/2017/asmjs+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us